# Strip x264 copyright information during ffmpeg copy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

I am trying to remove the copyright string from the generated mp4 file using ffmpeg (copyright string is already present in avi file).

I have an input avi which I'd like to [make 'streamable'](https://superuser.com/a/1249049/106444) and [remove all metadata](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg) so I used:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.avi -map 0 -movflags faststart -map_metadata -1 -codec copy output.mp4
```

Looking at the output it seems to be 'clean':

```
$ ffprobe output.mp4
[...]
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 01:36:21.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2036 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 704x396, 1392 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
```

But if one look carefully:

```
$ strings -50 output.mp4  | sort -u
x264 - core - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2010 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html
```

and:

```
$ strings -50 output.mp4  | wc
   1320   15840  125400
```

Is there a way to get rid of those 1320 copyright string from my target mp4 movie ?

---

Update: according to user Deltik this copyright string is set in function x264_sei_version_write:

- https://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=encoder/set.c;h=07a1261e180d001feb26b12d9179c7734ee979e6;hb=HEAD#l579

Which is hardcoded in x264_encoder_headers:

- https://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=encoder/encoder.c;h=074c4a5c2ba8f0a9df3778d2f1d593b22e09fa20;hb=HEAD#l2035

But since the ffmepg documentation seems to claims that units can be removed:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#filter_005funits

I was wondering if it was possible to remove existing copyright strings from an H.264 stream (eg. save some disk space) ?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but I'm seeing that the string comes from [the `x264_sei_version_write` function in `encoder/set.c`](https://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=encoder/set.c;h=07a1261e180d001feb26b12d9179c7734ee979e6;hb=HEAD#l579) in the x264 source code.  It looks hard-coded into [`encoder/encoder.c`](https://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=encoder/encoder.c;h=074c4a5c2ba8f0a9df3778d2f1d593b22e09fa20;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Why do you want to remove that?